# OrderBy a table angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table with ng-repeat, if the user selects one of the filters, it must be accommodated according to that filter, but I have the problem of accommodating it in a descending way the table according to that filter. if the user select "Limit" the table must orderBy Limit and if he select "Balance" orderBy Balance

```
enter code here

//Select for filter
<div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.form.type"
        ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in vm.typeOptions'
        ng-change="vm.showButton(vm.form.type)">
        </select>
</div>

//Table
<tr ng-repeat="x in vm.baseData " >
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Balance}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Limit}}</td>

</tr>


//Array Object
vm.baseData = [
      {'Name':"Aleatea", 'Balance':'$5,000.00','Limit':'$3,455.00'},
      {'Name':"Tiempo", 'Balance':'$34,754.00','Limit':'$2,234.00'},
      {'Name':"Seni", 'Balance':'$5,000.00','Limit':'$123.00'}
]
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: AngularJs 1.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically define the properties in an array which your table will be ordered by

`ng-repeat="x in vm.baseData | orderBy:vm.arr"`

Here's a working example

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("myCtrl", function(){

var vm = this;
vm.baseData = [
      {'Name':"Aleatea", 'Balance':'$5,000.00','Limit':'$3,455.00'},
      {'Name':"Tiempo", 'Balance':'$34,754.00','Limit':'$2,234.00'},
      {'Name':"Seni", 'Balance':'$5,000.00','Limit':'$123.00'},
      {'Name':"Seni", 'Balance':'$5,000.00','Limit':'$123.00'},
      {'Name':"Seni", 'Balance':'$6,340.00','Limit':'$143.00'}
];

vm.typeOptions = [{'name': 'Name', 'value': 'Name'}, {'name': 'Balance', 'value': 'Balance'}, {'name': 'Limit', 'value': 'Limit'}];

vm.orderFunc = function(){
  vm.arr = [];
  vm.arr.push(vm.type);
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

<div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.type"
        ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in vm.typeOptions' ng-change="vm.orderFunc()">
        </select>
</div>

<div>
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in vm.baseData | orderBy:vm.arr">
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Balance}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Limit}}</td>
</table>
</tr>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes the problem its for my arrat, ty so mucho for you answer

Comment: @Lizet please accept answer or upvote if the answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `orderBy` filter. Something like this:

`<tr ng-repeat="x in vm.baseData | orderBy:vm.query" >`

Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in vm.baseData | orderBy:vm.form.type: reverse| groupBy: 'name'" >
```

Comment: This only me grouped by name did not order me by

Comment: For example I have A, B , C , D, A, B , C, D instead of accommodating them by filter, gruopu them by A, A, B, B, C, C, D, D

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to use **orderBy** filter.
The first parameter would be the name of the property being used to order and the second a boolean indicating if the sort is in reverse order as default is ascending.

Take in mind that Balance and Limit are strings and will be ordered alphabetically. You can write a custom comparator or you can make sure to have the original numerical values as a property in your data.

```
//Table
<tr ng-repeat="x in vm.baseData | orderBy : vm.form.type : true" >
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Balance}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Limit}}</td>

</tr>
```